# ActiveRecord SQL Server Adapter not saving changes in transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2008, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm using the Rails Gem `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` to read from a MS SQL database. We are still on Rails 4.2.6 therefore we're using version 4.2.0 of the gem as well as tiny_tds.

Reads work fine from the database, however, writes are not having any effect.

In this example, I have an object that I'm updating a parameter on:

```
(byebug) VisualBase.transaction do visual_line.freight_note = 'test' 
end
"test"
(byebug) visual_line.freight_note = 'test'
"test"
(byebug) VisualBase.transaction do visual_line.save! end
true
(byebug)
```

And here's the logs:

```
SQL (1.3ms)  BEGIN TRANSACTION
SQL (0.7ms)  COMMIT TRANSACTION
SQL (4.2ms)  BEGIN TRANSACTION
SQL (1.5ms)  COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

There's no actual write to the database? Normally I see a log of the SQL commands being executed when it's reading from the database, but I'm not even seeing this when it comes to writing to it. Has anyone else come across this before?

In response to one of the answers below, here's my latest attempt:

```
VisualBase.transaction do 
    visual_line = VisualCustomerOrderLine.where('cust_order_id' => 'CO-304560').order(:rowid).first
    visual_line.freight_note = 'test' 
    visual_line.save!
end

VisualCustomerOrderBinary Load (1.4ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [CUST_ORDER_BINARY].* FROM [CUST_ORDER_BINARY] WHERE [CUST_ORDER_BINARY].[CUST_ORDER_ID] = @0  ORDER BY [CUST_ORDER_BINARY].[CUST_ORDER_ID] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 nvarchar(max)', @0 = N'CO-304560'  [[nil, "CO-304560"]]
  VisualCustomerOrderLine Load (3.8ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [CUST_ORDER_LINE].* FROM [CUST_ORDER_LINE] WHERE [CUST_ORDER_LINE].[cust_order_id] = N''CO-304560'''
  SQL (0.9ms)  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  VisualCustomerOrderLine Load (3.5ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [CUST_ORDER_LINE].* FROM [CUST_ORDER_LINE] WHERE [CUST_ORDER_LINE].[cust_order_id] = N''CO-304560''  ORDER BY [CUST_ORDER_LINE].[rowid] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY'
  SQL (38.0ms)  COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Unfortunately, when I checked the database, that value was still null. And looking at the log, I don't see a write attempt.

Comment: Is `visual_line` calling a method, or is that intended to be a variable name? You shouldn't be able to call a local variable defined outside the `transaction` block, so as written it looks like you're calling a locally available method over and over again. The behavior in your logs is to be expected from a transaction when nothing is being updated, either because the intended object is already in the desired state or because you haven't successfully assigned the desired state to the intended object before the `save!`.

Comment: @dan_a `freight_note` is a property of the object that I'm updating. `save` is a method.

Comment: Yes but what is `visual_line` itself? It's hard to identify what's going wrong here without seeing where that object is being defined. Given that a variable defined outside the block would be out of scope, it looks to me like it's actually a method call—and if it's a method call, the way that method is defined would probably be the clearest indicator of why your expected outcome isn't taking place.

Answer (score 0):

```
VisualBase.transaction do 
  visual_line = VisualLine.find(4711)
  visual_line.freight_note = 'test' 
  visual_line.save!
end
```

Comment: will that work for updating an item, or only for creating a new item? I'm trying to update an object and then save the update back to ms sql..

Comment: should work for both. actually you don`t need to wrap the code into a transaction if you are updating only one record

Comment: ok, I responded to your answer above in an edit. Thank you for taking the time to help, I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: that is all super weired. now i am curious. could you try without wrapping into a transaction. And could you share the whole source code on github or gitlab. My username is the same there dre-hh

Comment: The first strage thing ist that 3 select queries are made instead of one. The only explanation i see for not issuing the save call, is that fright_note method is somehow overriden or is not an active_record field. I would also debug following: remove transaction entirely, try save method without bang, log if it returns true, try VisualCustomerOrderLine.transaction {}. If you still encounter an error , try to create a minimal reproducable project on github with recent activerecord version. This one is too old, even if there is really a bug in it, it won't  be fixed any more by rails team.